# Use GitHub API with Android Studio

Tags: java, android, api, android-studio

we're trying to import an API located on GitHub into our app.
The API is located [here](https://github.com/iLexiconn/Magister.java).

We want to be able to use its functions from our other java files, and import the data we get into databases.
We don't know how to import and use the API. Thank you.

Comment: Did you read the readme of the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated on the `readme.md` on the page, add this to your `build.gradle` file:

> To use this API is your project, you just have to add this snippet if
>   you're using Grade:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        name = "ilexiconn"
        url = "http://maven.ilexiconn.net/"
    }
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
    compile "net.ilexiconn:magister:0.1.1"
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was putting them only in the Project build.gradle when I should've put it into the Module build.gradle too. Your answer made me see it.